# How to keep an aircraft stationary with an inoperative parking brake?

Tags: airline-operations, emergency-procedures, rejected-takeoff

After High Speed Rejected T/O and an imminent evacuation, how would a pilot keep the airplane stationary with an INOPERATIVE parking brake?

Comment: High speed rejected take off doesn't usually mean evacuation... What else is happening?

Comment: Turn off the engine(s), wait for someone to come out with wheel chocks.

Comment: Also why do you assume that the parking brake would be inop? RTO's at V1 are part of the certification process, which is brakes at "most worn" and no use of thrust reversers allowed. The brakes still work (unless there is something else going on). I think this question is based on a false premise.

Answer (score 5):

Keep pushing hard on the wheel brakes... And hope those do work, obviously.

If there's soggy ground next to the runway, let the aircraft roll onto that and the wheels should bog down into the mud.

There's precious little else you can do unless you want to deliberate drive the aircraft into something solid.

Comment: Who is going to volunteer to stay on the plane to keep their feet on the brakes while everyone else evacuates?

Comment: The pilot with the biggest fooot should stay.  ;)

Comment: Would that big-footed person really push so _hard_? I mean, in a car it's quite normal to keep pushing the wheel brakes instead of using the parking brake. At traffic lights, for example. After five minutes that might get annoying, but that's it. Basically the foot is _resting_ on the pedal, not really pressing it. Except on a hill, but that would be rather unusual for a runway.

Comment: @PerlDuck  I've never heard of a parking brake that "just failed." It could, but this is way, way far off in the realm of the hypothetical... high speed abort, followed by "hey, the parking brake isn't working." With engines off (part of evacuation checklist) & light wind, it isn't rolling anyway. In high winds or significant slope... yeah, maybe somebody sits there holding the brakes until somebody shows up with a chock. Highly, highly improbable.